# intent for direct turn by turn navigation on google maps along with mode of transit

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

My google maps intent code, It works and I have used this because I don't want to click the start button, this intent takes me to the turn by turn navigation:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = 
Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=22.5850383,88.3425874"); 
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri); mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps"); 
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

I want to specify the mode of transit as 'driving', I have tired

```
Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=22.5850383,88.3425874&mode=driving");
```

but it's not working.how do I specify transit mode as driving in the intent code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certain parameters you can supply via the navigation intent

> **Query**
>   **q**: Sets the end point for navigation searches. This can be a latitude,longitude or a query formatted address. If it is a query
>   string that returns more than one result, the first result will be
>   selected.
>
> **Mode**
>  mode sets the method of transportation. Mode is optional, defaults to driving, and can be set to one of:
>
> **d** for driving
>   **w** for walking
>   **b** for bicycling
>
> **Avoid**
>  avoid sets features the route should try to avoid. Avoid is optional and can be set to one or more of:
>
> **t** for tolls
>   **h** for highways
>   **f** for ferries

Example

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=22.5850383,88.3425874&mode=d");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

I think you have to append **&mode=d** to the uri instead of **&mode=driving**

Documentation
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents

Comment: @UpendraShah check this documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints